# tinymce paste text with color

Tags: tinymce

I'm using the paste plugin in my tinymce editor.

when i'm pasting a text inside of it (from a word document for example) ,               the text is copied but without it's color.

how can I paste the text with it's color?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: that depends from where you copy your content, if it is copied from word it might be able to keep the color. from other sources it depends

Comment: @Thariama: for now I'm trying to copy it from word , but it does not work. how can i copy the text with it's color from word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, i suggest you use the [paste plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste) then.
The paste plugin has a very usefull setting called [paste_retain_style_properties](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste).
Using this parameter you may define what styles you wish to keep.
You can select 'all' to keep all styles settings or use a comma-separated list.

Comment: thank's! it works partially.. if i copy languge diffrent then english the text becomes really small..